# "OR" operator in CONNECT BY PRIOR

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

The rows in the database are:

```
DATAID OWNERID PARENTID
111    123     133
976    346     111
987    976     657
```

I want to display all these rows but by using the following query only the top 2 rows are getting displayed and I need all the 3 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM DTREE  start with DATAID=111
connect by prior dataid=parentid OR dataid=ownerid;
```

It seems it is running only the `dataid=parentid` part and not the second one.

Comment: The `DATAID` value `987` is not connected to any other row through the parent or owner ID.  What output do you expect here?

Comment: DATAID value of 976 should be considered right? and after that since ownerid of row 3rd is 976(dataid=ownerid) hence it should get displayed?

Comment: `only the top 2 rows are getting displayed` ... this is what I would expect.

Comment: How can i modify the query to get the 3rd row as well?

Comment: The third row does not belong in the output.

Comment: Ok..But my output requires all the 3 rows. How would I then do that using connect by prior?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144890/discussion-between-ghostrider-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the PRIOR operator applying to the second occurrence of DATAID:

```
SELECT * FROM DTREE  start with DATAID=111
connect by prior dataid=parentid OR   prior  /* <-- MISSING!!! */  dataid=ownerid;
```

Alternatively:

```
connect by prior dataid in (parented, ownerid);
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent loop you should use NOCYCLE clause

```
SELECT * FROM DTREE  start with DATAID=111
connect by prior nocycle dataid=parentid OR prior dataid=ownerid;
```